# Python Spark reduceByKey does not apply to single elements

Tags: python, python-2.7, apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark

I'm new to Spark and I'm still trying to wrap my head around some of its concepts.
So, I have a list of key-value tuples, where both keys and values are also tuples.

```
val = [
   ((18, 13), (1, 1193, **5, 1**)), 
   ((18, 13), (1, 661, **3, 1**)), 
   ((9, 15), (1, 914, **3, 1**))
]
```

In the value tuples, I'm interested in the last two elements (remarked in bold).

I wish to perform the following : 5+3 and 1+1, since their tuples share a common key (18,13), while the last tuple, with values 3 and 1 should stay the same.
To achieve this, I do the following:

```
parsed_data = sc.parallelize(val)
result = parsed_data.reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[2]+y[2], x[3]+y[3]))
```

After applying these reduceByKey, I've got the following results:

```
[((18, 13), (8, 2)), ((9, 15), (1, 914, 3, 1))]
```

The reduceByKey function was not applied to the last tuple, since it doesn't have a pair to reduce with. Now I'm trying to understand how can I apply the reducebyKey anyway, to get the following output:

```
 [((18, 13), (8, 2)), ((9, 15), (3, 1))]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest here is probably just to map the values beforehand:

```
parsed_data.mapValues(lambda x: (x[2], x[3])).reduceByKey(lambda x,y: (x[0]+y[0], x[1]+y[1]))
```

(Apologies if the syntax is wrong, I'm a Scala guy rather than a Python guy).